# How to render a view before loading data

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-view

I've developed an app that communicates with cloud servers. Now I want to add some feedback when loading the data. For example, the user clicks a "get data" button to load the data, and the button text should change to "loading". And when the data is loaded, the text becomes "get data" again.

However, the first attempt did not work, and I did some research, it's because the view will not render until the task is finished. (I used AsyncTask to load the data). And I found a solution online informs that I should render the view in the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() method, so I tried the approach. Well, it does not work either.

It seems that there is a constraint that forces the rendering work to be done only after all the AsyncTask has finished.

Can someone enlighten me? It has bothered me for quite some time.

Comment: show the your code

Comment: just set text "loading..." in onPreExecute on the TextView and in onPostExecute  set Text back to "get Data"

Comment: I've figured out the problem. Never call AsyncTask.get(), since it will block the UI thread. Calling the AsyncTask.execute() is enough, and do the UI updates in postExecute().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I would suggest Retrofit for cloud API operations, if you want to use an AsyncTask, then that's fine. I would also suggest a ProgressBar / Dialog rather just updating some text.

> the view will not render until the task is finished

Unclear...

> I found a solution online informs that I should render the view in the onPreExecute() and onPostExecute() method, so I tried the approach. Well, it does not work either

Yes, that would work, so you should show *what you tried*.

> it seems that there is a constraint that forces the rendering work to be done only after all the AsyncTask has finished

Yes, there is a limitation that you cannot update the UI outside of the UI thread. That is why onPreExecute and onPostExecute exist.

---

I can guarantee those methods work.

[image]

```
public class ButtonActivity extends android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button button;
    private ProgressBar pg;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        super.onCreate(b);
        setContentView(...);

        button = (Button) findViewById(...);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);

        pg = (ProgressBar) findViewById(...);
        setLoading(false);
    }

    private void setLoading(boolean loading) {
        button.setText(loading ? "loading" : "get data");
        pg.setVisibility(loading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        new BackgroundTask().execute();
    }

    private class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            setLoading(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // some long operation
                Thread.sleep(3000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { }

            return null;
        }


        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Actually, I am trying to use a ProgressBar. But I met the same problem. Since the ProgressBar is also a view, I figured that it would be the same to demonstrate with the button text. The problem is that your code has the same issue with mine, the Button will not be rendered until the AsyncTask is finished, thus the button.setText("loading"); will wait until the AsyncTask finish and hit the onPostExecute() method, which change the text back, so there won't be any visible change to the user.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the button isn't rendered. The XML determines visibility and I've not toggled that.

Comment: I mean the text will not be updated to "loading" until the AsyncTask finishes. But when it finishes, it will immediately execute the onPostExecute() method and update the Button text to "get data" again, which makes the first update noticeable.

Comment: That shouldn't happen in my experience. It's set to loading when the button is clicked. The AsyncTask then waits indefinitely until onPostExecute happens (which may never happen)

Comment: That's what I thought at first. If Android execute the code line by line, this should be the case. However, it seems that there's certain mechanism prevent the rendering update from happening until the AsyncTask is done. I haven't figure out a solution...

Comment: It does run line by line. Except for the AsyncTask, which happens in a new thread, but still line by line

Comment: I figured out the reason. I used AsyncTask.execute().get() method, the get() method forces to wait for a result, which makes AsyncTask synchronous. Calling get() on the main thread will block the thread thus prevent any UI updates.

Comment: Yup. Calling `get()` is bad :) Glad you figured it out.